# Advice around persisting app data

Tags: android, sqlite, set, maps, persistence

I'm looking for some advice on the best approach in storing some data within my app. 
The app data is structured around a series of Set and Map collections (these collections hold primitive as well as simple object data types).

I want to store the state of these various collections within the app and my question is on what would be the preferred way to store this data? I am looking at SQLite databases but before I go down that road would like to be sure it is the best option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up using GSON API to serialize each Collection and then store in internal storage. I use JSON (within GSON api) to both store and retrieve the data. For a small collection of non-primitive type Sets and maps it works well.

GSON available from [google](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

To store data, Android provide several options:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

- To store few key-value, use Preference.
- To store structured data, use database (SQLite)